# How can I use a non-IFileEditorInput as the default EditorInput in my plugin?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am in the middle of creating an Eclipse plugin that will open an editor. Everything is mapped out well - my plugin.xml is set up correctly to open the editor for anything with the .xyz extension. The only thing holding me back is the `IEditorInput`.

I have a subclass of IEditorInput that I created for use with my editor. When I open the editor programmatically, I can create that EditorInput and open the editor correctly. However, when I open the editor using Project Explorer (Right click > Open With > My Editor), it is opened with a FileEditorInput.

How can I change the default behavior of Project Explorer to create the correct IEditorInput? Is there something in plugin.xml that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The editor doesn't get to choose the kind of editor input object it's given. It can use a IDocumentProvider to support different kinds of IEditorInput, but you should never artificially limit your editor to working with one kind of input, even if you do manage to change how the Project Explorer works.

Comment: It can use an IDocumentProvider for a form-based editor?

Comment: Probably, not, each implementation of IDocumentProvider is meant to handle a kind of IEditorInput and provide its contents as an IDocument for a ITextEditor to use. What's so special about your IEditorInput over just any kind of editor input?

Comment: I think I just don't understand how form-based editors work in eclipse. From what I've read, I need to have an MVC-like setup. I already have a representation of the model in the code, and presumably the view is my form. I'm just confused as to what the controller is. I thought it would be the EditorInput, but it looks like I'm wrong.